# Check SQL in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Is it possible to see the SQL QlikView generates when accessing the data in a database? (Something like in BusinessObjects "Show Script" option).
If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: How do you mean? Qlikview doesn't generate SQL per se, you write it yourself. Are you saying you'd like to show the quer(ies) on screen after reloading?

Comment: Sorry, you're right - I mixed up QlikView and BusinessObjects. Thanks!

Comment: hey oGeez! Can you please recommend me some good step-by-step tutorial on how to integrate Google Maps with QlikView 11.20 SR6. I know that in earlier versions this was possible, but I´ve heard that SR6 offeres much better visualisation. However, I couldn´t find online any good tutorial on this topic.

Comment: I believe when I did it myself I used this article: http://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-3136 and the resources provided in it. I'm using QlikView 11 and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You can use the wizzard to create SQL select by click. But this is only for the simple stuff like choosing table and columns.
However, the Direct Discovery feature creates a lot of SQL statement in the background. You can trace them by ODBC driver..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the QVW file where the SQL exists, go to the document properties:
Settings -> Document Properties -> General - check the 'Generate Logfile' checkbox.  On the next reload, a log file will now be created in the same folder as the QVW with a .log extension.  So if your QVW is called abc.qvw, there will be a log file called abc.qvw.log in the same folder.  In this log file, the SQL which is passed to the database will be logged (this will be the sql after any dynamic elements have been evaluated - e.g. any dynamic variables which might be injected into the where clause).