# Implementing Google Maps in QlikView 11 SR6

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to implement Google maps in my `QlikView` solution as it was implemented in this demo: [Ref Link](http://demo.heldendaten.net/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=Accesspoint/amMap_Example.qvw&host=QVS@demo.heldendaten.net&anonymous=true)

Our users have requested navigation options (Zoom in - Zoom out, Zooming scale) as it is displayed in the demo on the left side.

In addition, we have formally implemented Google maps in old version `QlikView` 11SR2.
The old version was implemented with images if I am not mistaken (I did not implement it).

Since the new version (`QlikView 11 SR6`) offers much better and more intuitive implementation of Google maps, our end-users want to have it. (The major improvement from our user's point of view is exactly previously mentioned navigational option - in older version a user had to select with a mouse the region in the map he/she wanted to analyze. In the new version user has zoom in-zoom out functionality).

I would very much appreciate if someone can explain me how to implement Google maps in `QV` with the Zoom in-Zoom out functionality.

Comment: @oGeez: hello mate! I created this new post in order to discuss about the Google Maps implementation in QV. I appreciate your feedback from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649142/check-sql-in-qlikview?noredirect=1#comment36396399_23649142 post. Above I have described what I am trying to acchieve. Can you please give me your thoughts about the challenge i am facing with? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adam, you should know that the `@` sign doesn't notify a user unless they've already commented. The fact that I came across your comment is pure coincidence. I'm not very caught up with the Maps API and don't trust myself enough to dish out instructions.